LP with infinitely many linear constraints
For a continuous linear map $f$, I have the following problem
$$
\max_{\mu} \int f(\mathbf{x}) \;\text{d}\mu(\mathbf{x})\\
\text{s.t.} \; c(\mathbf{z}) = \int f(\mathbf{x}) \text{d}\mu(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{z})\;, \forall \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^k
$$
Basically, we have infinitely many constraints (for each $\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{R}^k$) and each constraint has an integral over a conditional distribution (conditioned on $\mathbf{z}$) equal to some constant $c(\mathbf{z})$.
Is it even possible to solve such a problem. One challenge is that I am not very familiar with measure theory and am not sure about the literature currently out there that may be accessible for someone like me.
